# Reply output to an input

Tags: javascript, python, input, drop-down-menu, output

I'm new to Javascript, but I understand this is possible in Python as well (which I know a little of)

Say someone inputs ‘Hi’
How do you output a ‘reply’ back.

But a different reply if something different is entered i.e.

If **Hi** is inputted 'Hello there' is outputted

If **How are you** is inputted 'fine thanks' is outputted

etc.

I'd also like for those (Hi, how are you, what are you doing) to be selected from a dropdown menu (this will be on an HTML page)

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you would have a select menu (obviously):

```
<select id="greeting">
  <option value="0">Select a greeting</option>
  <option value="1">Hi</option>
  <option value="2">Hello there</option>
  <option value="3">How are you</option>
</select>
```

Then you'd attach an event listener to do something when the value of the select menu changes:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("greeting");
sel.onchange = function(){
  ...
}
```

Within the event handler you can then use the value of the selected option element to look up which greeting was entered and alert an appropriate response.

```
var greetings = {
    "1": "How are you?",
    "2": "Hello back!",
    "3": "Not bad"   
},
sel = document.getElementById("greeting");

sel.onchange = function(){
    if(this.value !== "0"){
        alert(greetings[this.value]);
    }
}
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/da4rd/)**